# How do i change the default sorting from primary key to another field when paging?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sorting, paging

Currently when paging it automatically sorts by the primary key. I want to be able to change this order to another field across the application, and overridden as you'd expect if someone specifies an order.

Note: This can't be done on an action by action basis and needs to be done in the config or context.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried up until now? Stack overflow is not a forum to do your work for you, think it as a guideline, whenever you need help. It wont help you doing this for you, because you wont learn from it

Comment: I have scoured the internet and I can't see a way to specify it in the db context or any annotations to apply to properties to specify this

Comment: You can use order by LINQ method while querying data using Context.

Comment: What you are failing to understand is we cant help you without seeing where is the problem. What structures are you trying to sort. I can give you a generic answer something like apply OrderBy(x => x.WhateverYouWant) but im not even sure if this is what you need

Comment: Posting your code, or what you have tried so far, what language framework you are using?

Comment: I'm using .net core with EntityFramework core and I've tried applying the default order by to the DbSet and tried looking for and config settings to apply at OnModelCreate. I basically want the created date to become the default orderBy when a collection is paged rather than the primary key (Guid). I'm hoping to add a tag to a property for this or set it in config somehow

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using functions in your database instead. Afterwards, simply use them from EntityFramework.